# Gatling test for async API

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I've an API endpoint that accepts three APIs like the followings:

- POST /runGraph => to start a job
- GET  /getProject => get status of a job
- POST /runGraphResult => will give job result

this is what I'm currently doing with Gatling

```
scenario("runGraph Scenario")
    .exec(
      http("POST runGraph")
      .post("/runGraph")
      .body(RawFileBody("rungraph_req_body.json"))
      .check(
        status is 200,
        bodyString is "\"\""
      ))
    .tryMax(1000) {
      pause(5)
      exec(
        http("GET  getProject")
        .get("/getProject").queryParam("id", env.projectId)
        .check(
          status is 200,
          jsonPath("$..status") in ("running", "successfully-executed", "failed")
        ))
    }
    .exec(
      http("POST runGraphResult")
      .post("/runGraphResult")
      .body(StringBody(s"""{"projectId":"${env.projectId}"}"""))
      .check(
        status is 200,
        jsonPath("$..run." + env.nodeId + ".result.count").ofType[Int] is numberOfRows
      ))
```

The problem with this is that the final report is giving me stats on individual requests while it would interesting to get the actual time it took the project to change status into `failed` or `successfully-executed`

[image]

How could I measure in Gatling the time different between the first API call to `POST /runGraph` and the one when the `GET /getProject` returned a status `failed` or `successfully-executed`?

Comment: You can group all that requests and measure execution time of whole group.

Comment: thanks @MateuszGruszczynski for the hint, I was not aware of such functionality, will check it out.